# Install Vowpal Wabbit on centos 7.4

Tags: centos, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install Vowpal Wabbit on centos 7.4. After getting code and running command `make`, then in last I get error-

```
inter -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MT vwdll.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vwdll.Tpo -c vwdll.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/vwdll.o
vwdll.cpp:2:19: fatal error: codecvt: No such file or directory
#include <codecvt>
               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [vwdll.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me how install vowpal wabbit?

Here is the github link for installation instructions- https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit

Comment: Something is missing from your environment. You need to install libboost-dev.   In my env (Ubuntu)  it is: 
 `$ dpkg -S codecvt.hpp ...
 libboost1.58-dev:amd64: /usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/config/codecvt.hpp`

Comment: @arielf I checked, `codecvt.hpp` is there in same path.

Comment: Ah well. There's not enough info in the snippet above for me to debug this. The above is clearly not just a `make`, it involved `autogen.sh` (which created `.libs`) earlier. I would recommend trying without `autogen/autoconf`.  To start: you need to restore the original Makefiles which were overwritten by `automake`, using `git checkout Makefile */Makefile`. Then try a simple `make`. Unless you have non-standard settings like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or headers/libs installed in non-standard places, a simple `make` might work out of the box.

Comment: @arielf I tried simple `make` only at first, I got the same error.

Comment: How about using precompiled static `vw` images for Linux/amd64? These should work on Ubuntu as well as on RHEL or CentOS. You can find a link to such binaries at   https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Download

Comment: Clone the master branch, I was able to install that on amazons linux (clone of centos i believe), I had the same error when I used vw 8.5

Answer (score 1):

The default compiler in CentOS 7 is gcc 4.8 that still has no full C++11 support including <codecvt> header, so you need to install and use a newer gcc version.

But if for some reason you can't, the good news is that <codecvt> is required by one of the auxiliary libraries that you probably don't need.

In this case you can just go ahead and build only the VW binary:

```
cd vowpalwabbit
make vw
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite sometime on a related issue, I was able to get vw running on CentOS 7 Docker. Here are the steps I took:

Before beginning, if you've already installed CentOS's `gcc-c++` package,
uninstall it.

1. Install newer developer toolset with a newer g++:

   ```
   yum -y install centos-release-scl 
   yum -y install  devtoolset-6
   /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-6 true
   ```
2. Install Boost library and related libraries:

   ```
   yum -y install boost-devel.x86_64 libboost-all-dev \ 
          libboost-program-options-dev
   ```
3. Install JDK if missing:

   ```
   yum -y java-1.7.0-openjdk java-1.7.0-openjdk-deve
   ```
4. Link newer g++ to path normally occupied by 'gcc-c++':

   ```
   ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++
   ```
5. Git clone and build:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git
   cd vowpa_wabbit
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```
6. Now you can use vw binary to access vowpal_wabbit via its [terminal interface.](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments) You may want to add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to be able to use vw from overall.

Thanks to Linux Uncle: https://ashokharnal.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/install-vowpal-wabbit-on-centos-machine/